# 'Walked on foot' or 'gone on foot'?

Tags: grammaticality, comparison, emphasis, redundancy

Which one is true?

> He had walked there on foot.

or

> He had gone there on foot.

Since 'walk' means *'to move or go somewhere by putting one foot in front of the other on the ground **[Oxford Dictionary]**'*, is it true to use it with 'on foot'?

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55234/is-walk-on-foot-acceptable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Redundancy for emphasis

You are correct that adding "on foot" is redundant, since "walk" already implies that. However, saying "walk on foot" is still grammatical. "On foot" functions as an adverb modifying "walk". It's redundant, but it adds *emphasis.* A person might say "walk on foot" in a situation where they wanted to emphasize the fact that you're not driving, or perhaps that a person's sore leg would give them pain.

Many common English constructions use redundancy for emphasis or extra clarity. Here are a couple more examples:

> Let's walk **on up** the hill.

You could just say "Let's walk up the hill." The "on" just adds some extra emphasis, also suggesting that you are continuing your current walk. Consecutive prepositions often work this way.

> It **may be possible** to find you a direct flight to Manchester.

"May" means "possibly", so technically that's redundant. One could also say, "Possibly you could find a direct flight to Manchester." Using two constructions in the same sentence that both mean "possibly" adds emphasis, either suggesting that the possibility is unlikely or expressing optimism by emphasizing the possibility.

If you'd like to read more about this, look up "[pleonasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm)". Something like it probably happens in your native language, too.

### Extended meanings

There's another reason why someone might say "walk on foot": you might have just been using the word "walk" in an extended sense. For example, you might just have been talking about riding in an Imperial Walker from Star Wars:

[image: Imperial Walker]

or referring to this old slogan from U.S. telephone companies, encouraging customers to look up a phone number in the phone book and call ahead before visiting a business:

[image]

or any of thousands of other possibilities.

Dictionary definitions can't possibly explain all the meanings that people can give a word. But people usually understand the difference between a primary meaning and an extended meaning. Redundancy can often help discourage a listener from understanding a word in an extended meaning in a situation where the extended meaning might seem relevant.

<sub>Picture sources: [starwars.com](http://www.starwars.com/news/weve-spotted-imperial-walkers-a-history-of-legged-war-machines), [Cazbah](http://blog.cazbah.net/2012/06/19/local-optimization-why-does-it-matter/let-your-fingers-do-the-walking/).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are acceptable, but the second is slightly better, precisely because the term *walk* is redundant in the phrase "walk on foot". People *go*/*flee*/*search*/*explore*/*cross* etc. **on foot** to wherever they need to go.

examples:

- But, instead, I often **go** home **on foot**.
- To **go** from North America to Asia **on foot** is theoretically possible but very difficult.
- Cars take us further and faster than we can **go on foot**
- That's where the man with the cell phone sat as the officers approached **on foot.**
- They searched **on foot** and with an infrared-equipped helicopter but found no one
- Away from the shore, the old city can be easily explored **on foot** in a few hours.
- It is considered a sign of devotion and humility to make the pilgrimage **on foot.**
- Lemus crossed through Guatemala and Mexico **on foot**, by bus and by hitching rides
- The clerk complied, and the man fled **on foot** with an undetermined amount of cash.
- Chinatown offers a wealth of good photo opportunities for a photographer **on foot**.
- Kent is ripe for exploration **on foot**, by bike, on public transport or in a car.
- It's a great city to wander around **on foot**, so pack a good pair of walking shoes